# How to change target of remote branch

Tags: git

After splitting my project in 2 branches, I have the following situation :

[image]

Remote branch "origin/master" targets my local "departements" branch . I would like this branch to target my local "master" branch instead. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point out that both master and origin/master are on a commit with the same description. If you really sure about this you can force push your master so that origin/master will point to the same commit as master.

```
git checkout master
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "with the same description" ?

Comment: @Harkonnen Both commits have "Zone de recherche" as a message (at least the first line ;-)

Comment: Ah ok, so yes, they have the same description (the HEAD of the "master" branch is just a cherry-pick of the HEAD of the "departements" branch)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly this is not the concept of git. The concept is to `merge` the branches.

So can open the branch from your master go to your master:

```
git checkout master
git branch departments
```

Then you have a new branch from master and you can work on it.

https://www.atlassian.com/en/git/workflows

Here are some interesting workflows to work with git.

Comment: you're right, but I thought that my work in "departements" branch would take less time than it did. So I didn't make a new branch for that. But I had to fix a bug, and I couldn't fit it in the state the project was. So I decided to split it in 2 branches. But I agree with you, and it's not the way I used to work.
Anyway, thank you for your link. It seems very interesting :)